# Simple Linear regression using for loop only with Python

Tags: python, arrays, regression

I am now doing a linear regression analysis. The input variable is Size. The output variable is Price. I store the set of data in 2D array. I know using NumPy is easy to conduct analysis but my professors told me to use for loop only to perform iterations. 
[Formula of interation is shown as the picture in the hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpGOV.jpg). Therefore, I decided the following code to perform the calculation:

```
#Structure of array (Stored in float), with structure like this [Room, Price]
array = [[4.0, 399.9], [5.0, 329.9], [6.0, 369.0]]

#Set initial value
theta_price = 0
theta_room = 0
stepsize = 0.01
item = 3

#Perform iterations
for looping in range(0, 50): #Loop 50 times
    for j in array[0]: #Call the value stored in array[0]
        for k in array[1]: #Call the value stored in array[1]
             theta_price_1 = theta_price - stepsize * (1 / item) * (sum((theta_price + theta_room * int(j) - int(k)))#Perform iterations of theta 0
             theta_room_1 = theta_room - stepsize * (1 / item) * (sum((theta_price + t + theta_room * int(j) - int(k))*int(j)))#Perform iterations of theta 1
             #Bring the new theta value to the next loop
             theta_price = theta_price_1
             theta_room = theta_room_1
             print(theta_price,theta_room)#Print the result for every loop
```

The above code was not function with error message at line 10 that:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

But if I remove the sum function, it works with incorrect calculation results. Therefore, I know it has some problems with the sum function and array but I don't know how to solve it?

Comment: the `sum` should be applied over all `x` and `y`, `array[0]` and `arrary[1]` in your case, in each iteration, but not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

As I metioned in the comment, `sum` should be applied over all elements in each iteration, that's what Batch Gradient Descent does. So the code should be:

```
theta_price = 0
theta_room = 0
stepsize = 0.1
item = 5
#Perform iterations
array = [
            [0,1,2,3,4],
            [5,6,7,8,9],
        ]

for looping in range(0, 500): #Loop 50 times
         theta_price = theta_price - stepsize * (1 / item) * (sum([theta_price + theta_room * int(j) - int(k) for j, k in zip(array[0], array[1])]))#Perform iterations of theta 0
         theta_room = theta_room - stepsize * (1 / item) * (sum([(theta_price + theta_room * int(j) - int(k)) * int(j) for j, k in zip(array[0], array[1])]))#Perform iterations of theta 1
         print(theta_price,theta_room)#Print the result for every loop
```

after 500 iterations with the 5 test data, I can get the result:

```
4.999999614653767 1.0000001313279816
```

which are expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, if the array is 2D array, the answer is incorrect. I have just added the format of array for reference. I tried to improve the answer by:

    for j[0], k[0] in array

The reason to make this change is that it seems working when using this format to find mean with "for a in array". Yet, the error message comes with expected an indented block. How to make changes to the answer to suite my situation.

Comment: Then you may use `numpy.array` for convenience.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to use NumPy as much as possible and I would like to modify the for loop to apply for my array.